# CS50 pset5 hashtable nodes

Tags: c, hashtable, cs50

I'm working on the hashtable version of pset5. I'm having trouble assigning the word value to the node I created. I haven't changed anything outside this while loop. I get an error from the line: node_ptr->word = word; It gives an error " error: array type 'char [46]' is not assignable." Why doesn't that line work?

```
// Buffer for a word
char word[LENGTH + 1];

// Insert words into hash table
while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
{
    //1) Create a node
    node *node_ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));

    //check memory != NULL
    if (!node_ptr)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //assign values to node 
    node_ptr->word = word;
    node_ptr->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing how `node` is defined. Consider working on a [mcve]. If you're trying to copy data from one character array to another consider `strcpy`.

Comment: In general `EOF` is not the only failure mode from `fscanf`. In your case this will result in a garbage string after the last word in file. Check for the number of matched arguments (!= 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the data member `word` inside node structure. I think your `node` is defined as

```
struct node
{
     char word[46];
     struct node_ptr *next;
};
```

so this case `node_ptr->word` is not a modifiable lvalue. So when you do assignment `node_ptr->word = word` it mean you violated this rule. You are trying to modify a lvalue that is not modifiable lvalue (node_ptr->word now is lvalue). You should use strcpy for copy string from `word` to `node_ptr->word` is a better way.